# github pages ignoring 2022 dates in liquid {{ page.date }}?? fine in local host

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

Using Jekyll to build a site, I have discrepancies between my local build and what GitHub pages renders.

I have a .html layout that uses the `date` property of the page for the title:

```
<h1>Meeting notes - {{ page.date | date_to_string }}</h1>
```

and the `date` is obtained thanks to the page's name `YYYY-MM-DD-notes.html`.

I then use a `for` loop to parse through all the meetings I have in `site.meetings` and display all meeting notes after one another in a `meetings.html` page.

My last two files are called: `2021-12-07-notes.html` and `2022-01-18-notes.html` so the first two titles in my meetings page should be:
**Meeting notes - 18 Jan 2022**
**Meeting notes - 07 Dec 2021**

Which is indeed what I get in my local build (along with all the previous ones, first meeting being in 2019).

But what GitHub pages renders is:
**Meeting notes -**
**Meeting notes - 07 Dec 2021**

As if he couldn't 'see' the 2022 date. Still working fine with all previous dates btw and again, on the local build.

Could someone explain this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was simply because I didn't have the right file name.

The file was actually called `2022-01-18_notes.md` and not `2022-01-18-notes.md` which made GitHub pages not recognise the date. Apparently my local jekyll is a bit more tolerant.